# how to repair windows login for one userid

Tags: windows-7

A laptop running Windows 7 is stuck on "Personalized Settings" setting up personalized settings for "Windows Desktop Update".

Is there a way to repair the desktop for a specific userid?

Note that I've seen some other suggestions of rolling back windows updates using restore, but the laptop doesn't have any problem logging in to a non-admin guest account, so I'm dubious that restore will work in this case.

Comment: So, you just don't want to try what will very likely fix it (a Windows System Restore)?  Why not?  Otherwise, can you access that user's folder(s) with an administrator account?  If so, why not backup their data, and then [Completely remove user account and create another with same name in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/410603/completely-remove-user-account-and-create-another-with-same-name-in-windows-7)?  Would that suffice?

Comment: I was dubious that windows restore would fix what appeared to me to be an issue with just one userid on the box, as opposed to a system issue, but did go ahead and do it.  Backing out all the recent updates did do the trick and the problem came back after windows update reinstalled fixpack 1.